# Find size of directories recursively and get a total

Tags: find, directory, disk-usage

I am using this command to find the folders I want and count up the size.

```
find . -type d -name 'tmp_c*' | xargs du -hcs {} \; +
```

My version of find does not support -exec. But, this works. However I am not sure if its giving me the right totals on the directories that contain my search string. When I run the command and pipe to less, I see it counting up each folders size, and then it outputs a total every so often. Like this:

```
140K    ./r/g/userid/attach/tmp_c_241091464_2
68K     ./r/g/userid/attach/tmp_c_58367014_undefined
2.3G    total
```

If I redirect the output to a file then grep on total, I get this:

```
2.3G    total
978M    total
1.1G    total
2.0G    total
1.1G    total
```

I *think* this is giving me the right numbers. But how can I take this command one step further and have it sum up the totals for a grand total on one line?

Comment: can you not get ncdu from epel?

Comment: Can't find an epel for RHEL3

Comment: Are you certain that none of the folders you want are nested?  If they are, you'll get some files double counted with the approach you are using.  What's wrong with `du -hs ./r/g/userid/attach`?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -name 'tmp_c*' -print0 | du -hcs --files0-from -
```

This assumes (recent enough?) GNU versions of `find` and `du`.

Comment: Afraid not. RHEL 3 and du (coreutils) 4.5.3. I get an error about the --files-from - argument being an unrecognized option.

Comment: --files**0**-from.  My commiserations.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323769/799204

> One alternate solution is to use awk:

but the script must be adapted for this case, try

```
find . -type d -name 'tmp_c*' -print0 | xargs -0 du -s | awk 'BEGIN { sum=0 } { sum+=$1 } END { print sum }'
```

output will be in decimal

Comment: This comand works but its sum total does not match what the command I was running totals up to. Not sure whats going on there.

Comment: Just as an FYI `-F " "` is unnecessary as space is the implied default value for FS.

Comment: Huh.  You could try `gawk` instead just to be sure, but I dunno.  (`gawk` specifically has docs that the number type should be good up to 2^51 or so).

Answer (score 1):

This should work, tested on my EL4 box... it's the oldest I have and makes me cringe, I don't know how you use EL3.

```
find . -type d -name 'tmp_c*' -print0|xargs -0 du -c|tail -1
```

Done with `coreutils-4.5.3-26`

Answer (score 0):

I checked epel starts at 5 not 3, so only option is custom script.

May aswell install ncdu;

https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncduit

I use it all the time, far easier, faster than any custom bash. (Can navigate through the dirs, saves loads of time).